# Argument list lengths differ in declaration

Tags: purescript

First day with purescript. Followed these steps

```
pulp repl
:paste
foo x y z = foo + bar
  where
    foo = x + y
    bar = y + z
```

Get an error

```
Error found:
in module $PSCI
at  line 1, column 1 - line 1, column 14

  Argument list lengths differ in declaration foo


See https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/ArgListLengthsDiffer.md for more information,
or to contribute content related to this error.
```

Went to the hyperlink specified in the error message but that page is almost blank.

I typed 2 spaces for each indentation. If I try to press tab key it says "Display all 136 possibilitie? (y or no)"

Also, is the :paste mode the only way to type in multiple line code in the typescript repl?

Comment: That works totally fine for me. Can you maybe post a video recording?

Comment: I think I am blind. I can see that I am using the word foo twice. I think that is the problem. If I call the outer function as baz then it compiles fine.

Comment: Actually, no. The definition with two `foo`s works just fine for me. `foo 1 2 3` returns `8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a problem with my code. I am using foo twice once in defining the outer function and then creating another foo inside. The works fine

```
baz x y z = foo + bar
  where
    foo = x + y
    bar = y + z
```